# Chrome snippets causes Promise.all to resolve after random(ish) amount of time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise

I have the following code:

```
var pizza = [];
var dough = ""
  , salami = ""
  , cheese = "";

function bakeDough() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        //simulate network delay
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("Baking dough..");
            dough = "";
            resolve();
        }
        , 1000);
    }
    )
}

function getCheese() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("Getting cheese..");
            cheese = "";
            resolve();
        }
        , 500);
    }
    );
}

function sliceSalami() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log("Slicing salami..");
            salami = "";
            resolve();
        }
        , 500);

    }
    )
}

function makePizza() {
    console.log("Making pizza...");
    Promise.all([bakeDough(), getCheese(), sliceSalami()]).then(()=>{
        pizza.push(dough);
        pizza.push(cheese);
        pizza.push(salami);
        console.log("Your pizza is ready! " + pizza);
    }
    );

}

makePizza();
```

So nothing else than a Promise.all with 3 promises that resolve after 1s, .5s, .5s. I am expecting it to resolve after ~1s.

If I run this code on jsFiddle, the results are the following:

[image]

Which is the expected result. (~1s) Same correct result is given with codepen.io.

However, running this in Chrome Snippets, gives oddly random values ranging from ~1.1s up to ~2s:

[image]
[image]

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: When you say "running this in Chrome snippets", what exactly does this mean?

Comment: Maybe you turned on CPU throttling (kind of a long shot, but I managed to reproduce with slowing down my CPU via the dev tools)?

Comment: For about 1 year now they have a feature that allows you to create Javascript 'snippets' directly from devtools. I find them pretty nice as you can run your JS code and see the result in the console. Somewhat similar to jsFiddle. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets

Comment: Does it resolve in ~1s on your end if you copy-paste into snippets? (or Console even! I found out it's the same thing. you can just copy-paste it in the console (make sure to have Settings -> Show timestamps on tho))

Comment: Works as expected in the latest Chromium and Chrome on Linux.